# java spring model object in jsp ( very strange )

Tags: spring, jsp

hi i have this in a jsp page

`<input type="text" id="jsonBom" value='${excNotice}'/>`

value='${excNotice}' is been interpreted as text in the jsp i get this text : ${excNotice} ... not the content of this variable that is been passed by spring controller ...   **very strange ...**

I have all the tag libs needed in the jsp ,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
```

Comment: value=${excNotice}. lose the quotation marks ;)

Comment: nop... not working :) thank´s ...